# Map entity from its id by reference

Tags: kotlin, spring-data-jpa

I have a Kotlin project using Spring JPA. I'm using clean code/architecture, so I'm splitting lots of concepts, with several "mappers" for repository objects, domain and exposed dto objects.
With that in mind, I have the following entities:

```
@Entity
@Table("projects")
internal data class ProjectJPA(
    @Id @Column val id: UUID,
    @Column val name: String,
    //other fields
) {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "projects", cascade = [CascadeType.REMOVE], fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    lateinit var samples: Set<SampleJPA>
}


@Entity
@Table("samples")
internal data class SampleJPA(
    @Id @Column val id: UUID,
    @Column(name = "project_id", insertable = false, updatable = false) val projectId: UUID,
    //other fields
) {
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    lateinit var project: ProjectJPA
}
```

This keep mapping between objects easier, since I don't have to retrieve the whole `ProjectJPA` entity to the `Sample` domain, for example, which only have the `projectId` reference.

But for my presentation model, I have to expose a "projection" from `Project`, which only have `id` and `name`.
So my mapper is something like:

```
internal fun SampleJPA.toPresentationModel() = SamplePresentationModel(
    id = id, 
    //other fields
    project = project.toMinimalRepresentation()
)

internal fun ProjectJPA.toMinimalRepresentation() = MinimalRepresentation(id = id, name = name)
```

When trying to add a new sample, I'm only mapping the `projectId`, since it is in the `SampleJPA` constructor. But when it comes to save the sample in the repository layer, it always says that the `projectId` is null.
It is like `ProjectJPA` from `SampleJPA` is not loaded based on `SampleJPA.projectId`.

How can this lateinit var be loaded based on the filled property id?